# How can i create a trigger to verify if new data exists on another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create trigger to insert new data to item table, but it has to be checked if the new data exists or not in item table. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER addItem
AFTER INSERT ON tempitem FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_name = NEW.item_name) THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO item (item_code, item_name, kategori, satuan)
        SELECT item_code, item_name, kategori, satuan FROM tempitem WHERE tempitem.item_name = NEW.item_name ;
    END IF;
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

The error says there are syntax error near "IF; END;" in line 8, but I can't find any mistake in the syntax.

Comment: Remove the `BEGIN` after `THEN`.

Comment: Isn't this a job for foreign key constraints? Not the insertion part but the "check" part. Then your app _has_ to do the inserts properly.

Comment: Don't answer in the comments please. Answer or don't, but if you do, do it in the proper place so that we can peer-review your contribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using SQL, we don't check if data exists to be sure we won't add duplicates. We attempt to insert it and we **place unique constraints**. If the record exists, database tells us *"No-no-no, it's already there"* and that's it.

Solution to your problem is not a trigger, it's placing a `unique` index on `item_name`. Since `item_name` is *probably* a textual column (char, varchar, text), usual technique is to create an additional column that will contain the **hash** of `item_name` and you apply unique index to that one.

All that's left is to utilize one of MySQL extensions to SQL, namely `INSERT IGNORE` syntax or `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and your problem is solved forever.

Comment: so, do you mean if we want to check if the data exists, you have to code it outside the SQL?

Comment: No. Read my answer carefully twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "BEGIN" in line 7, after "THEN" that may be causing the problem.

Try

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER addItem
AFTER INSERT ON tempitem FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM item WHERE item_name = NEW.item_name) THEN
        INSERT INTO item (item_code, item_name, kategori, satuan)
        SELECT item_code, item_name, kategori, satuan FROM tempitem WHERE tempitem.item_name = NEW.item_name ;
    END IF;
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This. OP, review [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html); there is no `BEGIN` there.